# Can't execute a COMPUTE statement

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to execute this simple statement on Northwind database

```
USE Northwind
SELECT  productid, orderid,quantity 
FROM [order details]
ORDER BY productid, orderid
COMPUTE SUM(quantity)
GO
```

But I this can't execute , I got this error

> *Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
>
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COMPUTE'.*

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using? The [2008 R2 docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181708(v=sql.105).aspx) say the feature will be removed in a future version of SQL Server, and COMPUTE is explicitly listed as [a feature that's no longer supported in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262.aspx).

Comment: Oh thanks , I am currently using the 2012 Version , here is the issue !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The COMPUTE clause is [no longer supported in SQL Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262.aspx). The documentation suggests using [ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 2):

Simple way to do compute:

```
Select columnname, count(*)
From tablename
Group by columnname
Order by columnname
Select 'SUM' , COUNT(columnname) from tablename
```