# Incorrect Syntax When Using Compute By on SQL Server Management Studio 2012

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2012

I have this code:

```
SELECT TransactionDate, CustomerName, TreatmentName, Price
FROM MsCustomer mc, HeaderSalonServices hss,DetailSalonServices dss, MsTreatment mt, MsStaff ms
WHERE mc.CustomerId = hss.CustomerId AND hss.StaffId = ms.StaffId
AND hss.TransactionId=dss.TransactionId and dss.TreatmentId=mt.TreatmentId
AND StaffName LIKE 'Ryan%' and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, TransactionDate)='thursday'
ORDER BY CustomerName, TreatmentName
COMPUTE SUM(price) BY CustomerName
```

It won't run, and it keeps saying "Incorrect syntax near 'COMPUTE'"
What do I do wrong?

This is my ERD:

[image: The ERD]

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Comment: @JW I'm using SSMS 2012

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't execute a COMPUTE statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12338697/cant-execute-a-compute-statement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COMPUTE / COMPUTE BY is discontiuned in SQL 2012. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144262.aspx
Instead of COMPUTE / COMPUTE BY use [ROLLUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Do following and you will get compute result:

Select columnname, count(*)
From tablename
Group by columnname
Order by columnname
Select 'SUM' , COUNT(columnname) from tablename

Comment: SELECT TransactionDate, CustomerName, TreatmentName, Price
FROM MsCustomer mc, HeaderSalonServices hss,DetailSalonServices dss, MsTreatment mt, MsStaff ms
WHERE mc.CustomerId = hss.CustomerId AND hss.StaffId = ms.StaffId
AND hss.TransactionId=dss.TransactionId and dss.TreatmentId=mt.TreatmentId
AND StaffName LIKE 'Ryan%' and DATENAME(WEEKDAY, TransactionDate)='thursday'
ORDER BY CustomerName, TreatmentName
SELECT 'SUM' ,Count(price) BY CustomerName